# Installing gtk by opam

Tags: ocaml, opam

I followed http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/introduction_to_gtk.html 
I installed OPAM, and then :

```
opam install lablgtk
```

It has finished successfully.

But when I typed:

```
Topdirs.dir_directory (Sys.getenv "OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH");;
```

I got:

```
Exception: Not_found.
```

When I am wrong ?

Comment: Possibly you need to run ``eval `opam config env` `` to set the appropriate environment variables. This line should probably also be in your `.bashrc` file or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the environment variable `OCAML_TOPLEVEL_PATH` is not defined. Use

```
eval $(opam config env)
```

to let **opam** set the appropriate value for you. See [the documentation for additional details](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/1.1/Advanced_Install.html).